# Node.js xmpp project connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, node-xmpp

Hi I am trying to create a project using Node.js node-xmpp NPM. I do not know how do I make MySql as the database to store newly created users, I can create a DB on MySql in my localhost but how do I connect Node-xmpp to that database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:-

Install mysql using npm install mysql.
Also you need to install express using npm.

**Sample Code**

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var connection  = require('express-myconnection'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');

app.use(

```
connection(mysql,{

    host: 'hostname',
    user: 'DBUser',
    password : 'DBPassword',
    port : 3306, //port mysql
    database:'DBName'

},'pool') //or single
```

);

Which XMPP server are you using ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am using node-xmpp, which includes node-xmpp-server, core, component and client

Comment: Are you really able to work with node-xmpp-server as XMPP SERVER ? I mean is it allowing you to create user account, one to one chat, MUC chat etc ?

Comment: I came to know that node-xmpp is a library similar to xmpphp (for PHP scripting), we need to have a real xmpp server running and connect the node-xmpp to the same, and then run the files

Comment: Which xmpp server you are going to use ... Openfire (Jave), Ejabbered (Erlang) or anything else?

Comment: you could use any xmpp server and use it with any xmpp client and use a library to connect and do activities